# Retaining the variable value for some consecutive intervals

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have been trying to model a constraint for a variable in an MIP formulation. My problem is like this; X(t) is a variable, whose value has to remain constant for some pre-defined consecutive periods after its value decreases. So, say at t=2, the X(t=2) value decreases from X(t=1), then X(t) should remain equal to X(t=2) for T consecutive periods following that decrease. Can anyone suggest me how can I do that in an MIP formulation?

Comment: What type of variable is $X(t)$?

Comment: It is a continuous variable has a bound like Xmin and Xmax; both of them are positive real number.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to also account for lower bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_t$ has constant bounds $[L_t,U_t]$.  Introduce binary decision variable $d_t$ to indicate whether $X_t$ decreased from the previous period, and impose the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
X_{t-1} - X_t &\le (U_{t-1} - L_t) d_t &&\text{for all $t$} \tag1\label1 \\
(L_t-U_{t+i}) (1-d_t) \le X_t - X_{t+i} &\le (U_t - L_{t+i}) (1-d_t) &&\text{for all $t$ and $i\in\{1,\dots,T\}$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}

Constraint \eqref{1} enforces the logical proposition $X_t < X_{t-1} \implies d_t = 1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the logical proposition $d_t = 1 \implies X_t = X_{t+1} = \dots = X_{t+T}$.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply and I apologize for this perhaps too obvious question. Did you mean that the middle term in the second equation will be something like at any certain time t, if the T=4 hours then ; X(t)-X(t+1)-X(t+2)-X(t+3)-X(t+4) or did you just mean that there will be four equations, with X(t)-X(t+1); X(t)-X(t+2), .... It seems to me that using a summation we can implement it like this sum(i=1 to 4, X(t)-X(t+i))

Comment: Constraint \eqref{2} corresponds to your second interpretation, with only two $X$ variables at a time.